# Dónde poner énfasis

Tags: vocabulario, pronunciación

Buenos, amigos.  Yo quiero comenzar a decir que mi Espanol es muy malo, pero estoy aprendiendo.

Mi pregunta es, cuando hablas una palabra con dos piezas, como sabes donde poner el enfasis?

Por ejemplo:

Dices "BES-tia" y no "bes-TIA".  Por que?

Otra vez, lo siento por mi mal Espanol y gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Me gusta que hables en español, sigue así, hablas bien, pequeños errores pero sigue así.

Comment: Buena pregunta (y buena respuesta la de Guifa). Algunas correcciones que te pueden interesar: 1. español (sin mayúsculas), pues sólo se capitalizan los nombres propios pero no idiomas ni nacionalidades. 2. "Buenas, amigos", a cualquier hora, o "buenos días / buenas tardes-noches". 3. Usualmente, decimos o pronunciamos palabras, y hablamos idiomas/lenguas.

Comment: Gracias por las palabras buenas y la ayuda!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es fácil si ya sabes escribir la palabra que quieres decir. Hay tres reglas fáciles (síguelas en orden)

1. Si hay tilde, acentúa la sílaba que lo alberga.
2. Si acaba en *A, E, I, O, U, N* o *S*, acentúa la penúltima sílaba.
3. Acentúa la última sílaba.

Así que, en palabras como *carmesí*, *espíritu*, *llevándosemelo*, el tilde te indica dónde poner el acento.

En palabras como *una*, *este*, *cursi*, *terminales*, *caminan*, ves que no tienen tilde (por que no se sigue la primera regla), pero sí terminan con una de las letras *aeiouns*. Así que, tienes Una, ESte, CURsi, termiNAles, y caMInan.

Finalmente, en palabras como *ajedrez*, *abad* o *reloj*, no hay tilde (no se sigue la primera) ni acaban en *aeiouns* (tampoco la segunda). Así que hay que seguir la tercera, es decir la última sílaba: ajeDREZ, aBAD, reLOJ.

En tu ejemplo de *bestia*, sería posible escribir (ojo: no son palabras verdaderas) *bestía* (bes-TI-a) y *bestiá* (bes-TIA)

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Yo comprendo!